# SQL Server Execution Timeout Expired

Tags: sql-server

Is there something wrong with my code? I get an exception:

> Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I'm trying to update a dynamic table with dynamic columns depending on the searched facility of user

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_UPDATE_FACILITY
    @featid int,
    @facilityid int,
    @updatetbl as TABLE_UPDATE_FACILITYDETAILS READONLY 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @tblname AS NVARCHAR(255);
    SET @tblname = (SELECT dbo.FNC_Search_GetSearchTable(@facilityid));

    DECLARE @key varchar(255);
    DECLARE @value varchar(255);

    DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR

    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
        SELECT col_key, col_value FROM @updatetbl

    OPEN @MyCursor 

    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @key , @value

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        IF(@key != '' and @value != '')
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRY  
                SET @value = (CAST ( @value AS varchar(255)));
            END TRY  
            BEGIN CATCH
                SET @value = (CAST ( @value AS float));
            END CATCH;

            DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(500);
            SET @sSQL = 'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@tblname) + ' SET ' + QUOTENAME(@key) + ' =  @value WHERE FEATID = @featid'

            EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL , N'@value VARCHAR(255), @featid INT', @key, @featid

            FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @key, @value
        END
    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END
GO
```

Is there a way to loop through rows of table then get the values per rows of table

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @Value is already varchar(255), why would you cast it to varchar(255)?

You could update all columns at once instead of having an update statement per column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not have any "execution timeout", while the clients can set it.

If you use C#, the default Execution timeout is 30 seconds that is too small.
Of course you should investigate what your query is waiting for using `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks`, but if 30 seconds are not enough to your code to complete, just change this Execution timeout value to smth else (0 = infinite)

Comment: thanks but i already optimized my query so it doesn't exceed 30 seconds

Comment: Your update can be blocked by any SELECT, and you can see who blocks it in sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks